# php json_decode issue on browser

Tags: php, json

I have on DB2 table that stores one Json string on one of the fields and I need to get this value and display on a browser, so this is here my problem begins...

Some json string has German chars that for some reason only when I execute the php from a browser gets error 5 on `json_last_error()`, if I execute the same script on terminal, it execute with success.

Another thing is, if I get the same json string, and put direct on a var instead of get the var from DB2 using `db2_exec()` it works too.

so I built one script to test, and here my tests:

EXECUTING FROM TERMINAL:

```
message to be decoded:

From DB:
{"location":" Ã–sterr","street1":"straÃŸe"}

From var:
{"location":" Ã–sterr","street1":"straÃŸe"}

-------------------------------------------------------------

Json Decode From Var...
stdClass Object
(
    [location] =>  Ã–sterr
    [street1] => straÃŸe
)


-------------------------------------------------------------

Json Error Checking Json Decode Var...

 - No errors

-------------------------------------------------------------

Json Decode From DB...
stdClass Object
(
    [location] =>  Ã–sterr
    [street1] => straÃŸe
)


-------------------------------------------------------------

Json Error Checking Json Decode DB...

 - No errors
```

EXECUTING FROM BROWSER:

[image: Execute from browser]

I already tried:

`utf8_encode()` - but this does nothing and the var still the same.

`iconv` - get an error saying that there is one invalid char.

I am running out of options to solve this.. I really need help on this.

Thank you.

Comment: Those are in no way validly encoded "German characters". `json_decode` fails because it needs UTF-8; and looking at what you show I can't fault it, because you're giving it *some garbage* in who knows what encoding. An ß looks like ß in properly handled UTF-8, not "ÃŸ". Please peruse the duplicate and start by handing UTF-8 properly [front to back](http://kunststube.net/frontback).

Comment: mb_detect_encoding() returns that the string is UTF-8..

Comment: I cant find the same question as mine, can you send me the link of the question?

Comment: Not the *same* question as yours, but a question about using UTF-8 all the way through. (At the very top of your question, in case you missed it.) Cover your basics there first; at the moment it's completely unproductive to speculate about what encoding you're using incorrectly where when all we see is garbage characters to begin with.